# Override JS in third party webpage using Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm trying to override a JS function inside a third party webpage with the purpose of WebScraping using Selenium + ChromeDriver.

Why go through all this trouble you may ask.
At some point there is this call inside a JS function when I try to click on the "submit form" button:

```
xxxx = window.showModalDialog("...");
```

This is just a confirmation pop-up for the user. Thing is that showModalDialog is no longer supported by Chrome/Firefox/Edge, only by IE. Can I use IE to achieve the results? No, as IEDriver configuration for IE 11 needs a higher "security clearance level" (aka admin privileges) than I am able to obtain.

The best solution would be just replace the above code with:

```
xxxx = true;
```

Submit Button HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="botaoFlatConfirmar" 
onclick="if (critica("some test") 
{ return Submeter('E', this, 'XXXXXXXXXX');; }" barrabotao="true" style="white-space: nowrap; ....</button>
```

and inside Submeter() there is this piece of code:

```
if (abreAviso("xxxx")){ form.submit();}
```

Which bring us back to abreAviso():

```
function abreAviso(msg, tipoMensagem, tituloTexto1, conteudoTexto1, tituloTexto2, conteudoTexto2, tituloTexto3, conteudoTexto3, altura, largura)
{   
    var retorno = false;
    if (altura == null) altura = 200
    if (largura == null) largura = 400
    if (tipoMensagem==null) tipoMensagem = 'I'

    if (tituloTexto1==null) tituloTexto1 = ''
    if (conteudoTexto1==null) conteudoTexto1=''
    if (tituloTexto2==null) tituloTexto2=''
    if (conteudoTexto2==null) conteudoTexto2=''
    if (tituloTexto3==null) tituloTexto3=''
    if (conteudoTexto3==null) conteudoTexto3=''
    retorno = window.showModalDialog("/XXXXXXXXXXXXX =" + msg + "&tipoMensagem=" + tipoMensagem + "&conteudoTexto1=" + conteudoTexto1 + "&conteudoTexto2=" + conteudoTexto2 + "&conteudoTexto3=" + conteudoTexto3 + "&tituloTexto1=" + tituloTexto1 + "&tituloTexto2=" + tituloTexto2 + "&tituloTexto3=" + tituloTexto3,"avisoPadrao","center:yes;dialogWidth:" + largura + "px;dialogheight=" + altura + "px;status=no;");
    return retorno; 
}
```

Can I force the form submit? No, because I need the data validation code inside Submeter() (which is 2000+ lines long);

So, ideally I would like to override abreAviso() if possible.

I read a lot of StackOverflow topics on this, but I was not able to come up with a working code.

I tried to implement something with JavaScriptExecutor and failed, because I need to run it after the Submeter() function.

**Important Information:**

I really inexperienced when it comes to JS.

I can override the abreAviso() function manually with Chrome.

It would be really nice if one of you guys could point me to a solution on how to override the function using Selenium and C# or suggest some other tool/solution method.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to override the fs function using selenium js executor. (checked the solution in python and converted to C#)

```
IWebDriver driver; //may be assigned somewhere before this line.
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.abreAviso=function(){return true};");

// you check the output by executing this function
string fReturnVal = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return abreAviso()")
// print the fReturnVal (this will be True)
```

Output:
[image]